# How to pass data from onCreate() to onSaveInstanceState()?

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, oncreate, onsaveinstancestate

I have an onCreate() function and an onSaveInstanceState() function in my Main Activity. I have declared a Map in my onCreate() and I want to access the keys of that Map in my onSaveInstanceState() function, so as to save them to the outState bundle.

```
class MainActivity: AppCombatActivity(){

     override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        //Want to access the iconMap here, but it is outside of the Map's scope. How do I access it?
    }

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val iconMap = mapOf("contactlessIcon" to getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contactless_24px), "fingerprintIcon" to getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_black_48dp), "codeIcon" to getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_code_24px))
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to Android programming, so this might be an easy fix. I want to access the `iconMap` in the onSaveInstanceState() but it is outside `iconMap's` scope. I cannot make `iconMap` a global variable, for this crashes my app.

Comment: What exactly of `iconMap` are you saving in `onSaveInstanceState()`? As a rule, the only thing you should be saving is the user's state, not strings or Drawables that are always going to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ianhanniballake commented - you shouldn't be saving Drawables that are always the same. In this case it's especially unnecessary since you're `onCreate` will be called again whenever the activity is restored.

But, to answer your question, you can do it like this :

```
class MainActivity: AppCombatActivity(){
      // define it here, so it's a member of the class
      lateinit val iconMap: Map<String, Drawable>

      override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        //now you can use it here
      }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 
        //set its value
        iconMap = mapOf("contactlessIcon" to getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contactless_24px), "fingerprintIcon" to getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_black_48dp), "codeIcon" to getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_code_24px))
     }
}
```